# Blog Pagination URL: Remove "P" from url and get correct page number

Tags: url

I want my URLs to be like the following: domain.com/blog/2

Currently they are: domain.com/blog/P6

RIght now if I show 6 articles per page, my pagination will jump by 6.

For instance, Page 1 will be /, page 2 will be /P6/, page 3 will be /P9/, ect.

Comment: I guess this is not possible in current EE pagination system

Comment: So the most common and practical URL structure isn't possible with EE? That's insane. There has to be a way to achieve it. Who the hell has P3, P6, P9, ect for their URLs? What were they thinking?

Comment: They thinking to set offset in URL so they can easily get next batch of data. So P10 id pagination where P stands for pagination and 10 is an Offset.

Comment: Yes I understand it's an offset. I'm saying it's stupid to have URLs like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

- On `index` template, set `Allow PHP?` to `Yes`
- On `index` template, set `PHP Parsing Stage` to `Input`
- On `single` template, set `Template route override` to `/blog/{url_title:regex[(((?!(\d+|category\/)).)+?)]}` (make sure to swap blog for your index page url)

Inside `index` template, use the following:

```
<?php $entriesperpage = 6; ?>
      {if segment_2}
        <?php
        $entries = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry')
         ->filter('channel_id', 4) // or whatever you want/need to filter on
         ->filter('status', 'IN', array('open', 'other_status'))
         ->order('title', 'ASC')
         ->all();
         $totalentries = count($entries);
         if ( ($totalentries / (({segment_2} - 1) * $entriesperpage)) < 1 ) {
           $redirect = "TRUE";
         } else {
           $redirect = "FALSE";
         }
         $totalpages = ceil($totalentries / $entriesperpage);
         ?>
         {if <?php echo $redirect; ?>}
            {redirect='404'}
         {/if}
      {/if}
      {exp:channel:entries channel="articles" dynamic="no" {if segment_2} offset="<?php echo ({segment_2} - 1) * $entriesperpage; ?>" {/if} limit="<?php echo $entriesperpage; ?>" paginate="bottom"}
        <a class="post" href="{route='blog/single' url_title='{url_title}'}"></a>
      {/exp:channel:entries}
      <div class="pagination">
        {if segment_2}
          <?php $prevpage = {segment_2}-1; ?>
          <a href="{site_url}blog<?php if ($prevpage != 1) { echo '/' . $prevpage; } ?>" class="page-prev">Prev</a>
        {/if}
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++) { ?>
          <a href="{site_url}blog<?php if ($i != 1) { echo '/' . $i; } ?>" class="{if (!segment_2 && (<?php echo $i; ?> == 1)) || (segment_2 == <?php echo $i; ?>)} active{/if}"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        {if !segment_2}
          <a href="{site_url}blog/2" class="page-next">Next</a>
        {if:else}
          {if segment_2 != <?php echo $totalpages; ?>}
          <a href="{site_url}blog/<?php echo ({segment_2} + 1); ?>" class="page-next">Next</a>
          {/if}
        {/if}
      </div>
```

This will produce the following urls:

- website.com/blog
- website.com/blog/2
- website.com/blog/3
- etc

Make sure to set `$entriesperpage` to your desired entries per page, `channel_id` to the correlating ID of channel you're displaying, and update `blog` to your index page url.

We are essentially using our own pagination logic, and I'm sure this could be cleaned up a bit.

Note that this will display all page links, so you may want to add custom logic if dealing with many pages.